# Subroutines in VBA - only performs the first (Excel)

Tags: vba, excel

I want to assign a macro that copy several values from one sheet to another, and so far I've come to this:

```
Sub botaoconfirmar_click()
Range("C6").Select
Selection.Copy

Worksheets("Historico").Select
lMaxRows = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

Range("B" & lMaxRows + 1).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _    
False, Transpose:=False

Range("C59").Select
Selection.Copy

Worksheets("Historico").Select
lMaxRows = Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row

Range("C" & lMaxRows + 1).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial , Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
False, Transpose:=False
End Sub
```

The problem is that when I click the button with this macro it only performs the first action. If I change the order, it still performs only the first action (former #2).

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specifically to your problem, you're not qualifying the `Sheet` associated with the `Copy` statement. So, when you copy `Range("C59")`, your code is still on `Sheets("Historico")`. Change both of your initial selection statements to, for example, `Sheets("Data").Range("C6").Select`.

On a side note, the code is not running optimally. There is no need to select each cell and sheet that you intend to work with. The best way to write the code would be (again, assuming the data is in a sheet named "Data"):

```
Sub botaoconfirmar_click()
    Dim wsData As Worksheet
    Dim wsHistorico As Worksheet
    Dim lMaxRows As Long

    Set wsData = Worksheets("Data")
    Set wsHistorico = Worksheets("Historico")

    lMaxRows = wsHistorico.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    wsHistorico.Range("B" & lMaxRows + 1).Value = wsData.Range("C6")

    lMaxRows = wsHistorico.Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
    wsHistorico.Range("C" & lMaxRows + 1).Value = wsData.Range("C59")

End Sub
```

Comment: This worked! Thank you so much, I was since yesterday trying to make it work :D

Comment: @Joao If it's as needed, please mark the question 'answered'.